# Set Duplicate Row as One Row AND one Different Column Value Merge

Tags: sql

I have ONE table like this [image]

in this table orderID column is repeat but its CollectDate is different

So i want to SET MY table AS means IF OrderID Same then concatenate Collect Date

[image]

MY query is following and its work

```
            SELECT distinct df.OrderId as OrderId,df.FileName as FileName, df.RandomKey as RandomKey,      
            df.ClientId as ClientId, df.ProjectId as ProjectId, df.Status as Status,df.UserId as UserId,       
            df.emailTo as emailTo,df.PackageType as PackageType,df.RequestedDatetime as RequestedDatetime,
            STUFF(
            (SELECT '  |  ' +  convert(varchar(10),ord.CollectDate, 101)                                                

            FROM SMXPSU.OrderDetails ord
            WHERE df.OrderId =ord.OrderId --and ord.OrderId in(getdate()-30) 
            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS CollectDate
            FROM SMXPSU.downloadfiles  AS df                  
            INNER Join
              SMXPSU.OrderDetails ord (NOLOCK) 
            ON df.OrderId=ord.OrderId    
            WHERE df.ClientId='shaw22'  and df.PackageType='Hard Copy' and df.RequestedDatetime>=getdate()-30 
            GROUP BY df.OrderId,FileName,PackageType,RequestedDatetime,RandomKey,ClientId,ProjectId,Status,UserId,emailTo,PackageType,RequestedDatetime,CollectDate

            order by df.OrderId desc ![enter image description here][3]
```

But Output give me like this

[image]

Means if CollectDate same then cumming multiple time but i want only one time if same

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? What is the data type of CollectDate?

Comment: @KiranHegde CollectDate type is datetime

Comment: Which DBMS? SQL Server? My SQL?

Comment: @KiranHegde SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following query

```
;WITH order_cte
AS
(
    SELECT OrderId,RandomKey,PackageType,RequestedDate,
    (
        SELECT CAST(CAST(orders.CollectedData AS DATE) AS VARCHAR)  + '-' AS 'text()'   
        FROM Orders WHERE Orders.OrderId=o.OrderId 
        FOR XML Path('')
    ) [CollectDate]
    FROM Orders o
    GROUP BY OrderId,RandomKey,PackageType,RequestedDate
)
SELECT OrderId,RandomKey,PackageType,RequestedDate,LEFT([CollectDate],LEN([CollectDate])-1) AS [CollectDate] 
FROM order_cte;
```

Comment: Did you try DISTINCT in the query like below
DISTINCT '  |  ' +  convert(varchar(10),ord.CollectDate, 101)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT OrderId, RandomKey, PackageType, RequestedDate, 
CASE 
WHEN COUNT(*)=1 THEN CAST(MIN(CollectDate) AS VARCHAR(20))
ELSE CAST(MIN(CollectDate) AS VARCHAR(20)) + '-' + CAST(MAX(CollectDate) AS VARCHAR    (20)) AS CollectDate
FROM
Table
GROUP BY OrderId, RandomKey, PackageType, RequestedDate
```